# SQL Server 2008 time stamp subtraction to get total seconds (the time stamps are always changing)

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, datediff

I have little experience with SQL Server and need some help as our DBA is no longer with us and we are in the process of looking for a new one.

Background: We are using two columns in a table, `customVariable2` and `customVariable3`. `customVariable2` is the first timestamp and `customVariable3` is the second timestamp. The time format is HH:MM:SS PM PDT.

I need to find the difference in time between `customVariable2` and `customVariable3` and then show that difference in another column. If it returns a value in seconds or minutes that is fine.

I am not sure what other information is needed from me for the community to be able to help. Please let me know if more information is needed and i can provide that.

Again I am a completely green when it comes to writing queries.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: would http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx DATEDIFF() work for you?

Comment: I have tried DATEDIFF and I might not be formatting it properly, but i can't seem to get it to work because it expects a full date not just a time of day.

Comment: what are the data types for customervariable2 and 3. Can you provide an example?

Comment: datediff will accept a time, date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset for the start/end parameters.  That's most likely the easiest route as Christopher Johnson mentioned.  Giving us an example of your code will help us narrow down your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
select DATEDIFF(second,'12:12:12 PM','1:13:13 PM')
```

but this does not:

```
select DATEDIFF(second,'12:12:12 PM PDT','1:13:13 PM PDT')
```

If the data is in varchar's and includes the "PDT", I would suspect what you need to do is

```
select DATEDIFF(second,replace(customVariable2,' PDT',''), replace(customVariable3,' PDT',''))
```

After the additional question in the comment, to store the result of the difference in timestamps:

```
update tablename
set customVariable4 = DATEDIFF(second, replace(customVariable2,' PDT',''), replace(customVariable3,' PDT',''))
```

If the column to store the difference (customVariable4 in my sample code) in doesn't already exist, you'll need to add it to the table.

Comment: Now how do i add a new column to the results i get with the returned value.  Currently it opens a new results table with the time difference.  I need to have it be inserted into the original table.  If more informatino is needed please let me know and i'll add it.

Comment: So the answer depends on if the column already exists or if you need to add it. I'll edit my answer, still too new at actually posting.